# L'alinéa est-il de plus en plus fréquent dans les textes d'information et marque-t-il encore le passage d'un « groupe d'idées » à un autre ?

Tags: typographie, style-de-rédaction, présentation, stylistique

L'[*alinéa*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/alin%C3%A9a) « est la marque d'un retour à la ligne », pouvant désigner la « portion de texte comprise entre deux retours à la ligne » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alin%C3%A9a)) et « correspond à une pause très marquée, [qui] s'emploie surtout quand on passe d'un groupe d'idées à un autre » (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §118 b). [Alinéa](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/accolade-allemand.html#Alinea) et [paragraphe](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/pacte-point.html#Paragraphe) ne sont pas exactement synonymes, plusieurs alinéas pouvant constituer un paragraphe etc., mais pour les fins de la discussion on parle essentiellement de la longueur et donc incidemment du nombre de (compositions en) pavés (ou usuellement de *paragraphes*) dans un texte d'information...

---

- Est-il vrai qu'il y a de plus en plus d'alinéas, et sont-ils donc de plus en plus courts, en journalisme (dans les journaux), est-ce perceptible, mesurable : le cas échéant, qu'est-ce qui expliquerait ce choix et quelle en est la conséquence ; serait-ce aussi le cas plus généralement dans les textes ?
- Concrètement, qu'est-ce qu'un *groupe d'idées* par opposition à une
  *idée*, qu'est-ce qu'un *long/court* alinéa (combien de lignes ; y a-t-il un usage, une tradition à cet effet), dirait-on que l'alinéa marque de plus en plus le passage d'une idée, voire d'une phrase, à une autre ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas remarqué ça dans les journaux mais on ne lit peut-être pas les mêmes. Qu'est-ce qui te fait penser qu'il y a une évolution dans les journaux ? J'ai bien une écriture journalistique avec une seule phrase par paragraphe, mais c'est en anglais : la BBC.

Comment: La pratique traditionnelle est d'avoir un alinéa de la taille d'un cadratin, donc déjà assez court, j'essaye de repasser ce soir pour une plus longue réponse :)

Comment: @Gilles Je suis tombé par hasard sur [ceci](https://books.google.com/books?id=gEadcdqwFDUC&lpg=PA139&dq=fr%C3%A9quence%20alin%C3%A9as%20augmentation&pg=PA139#v=onepage&q=fr%C3%A9quence%20alin%C3%A9as%20augmentation&f=false). Je lis surtout _Lapresse_ et ça varie selon les journalistes. Ensuite j'ai cru remarquer ça sur le site même ; probablement que je suis habitué à de plus longs paragraphes que la moyenne donc je le remarque plus ? Enfin j'ai noté sur mon mobile que je ne peux envoyer (sms) un para du genre de ceux que j'écris normalement, ça bloque, je dois en faire des plus petits..Merci!

Comment: @Gilles Oui, dans les journaux en anglais au Canada le paragraphe d'une ou deux phrases est normal : c'est même le style qu'on enseigne aux apprenants (au moins en 9e année et dans les journaux d'étudiant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je suis journaliste et effectivement je pense qu'on peut dire qu'il y a une tendance à  retourner à la ligne plus souvent dans les articles de journaux papier et en ligne actuels.

Selon moi, cette tendance vient du fait qu'on est passé à une écriture plus courte, plus simple et plus efficace. Les articles sont de plus en plus courts et on essaie de simplifier au maximum : une idée = un paragraphe.

Autre raison à cela, selon moi : l'écriture web. Sur le web, les formats sont encore plus courts car on considère que les gens ne vont pas lire de longs papiers sur smartphone ou tablette. Ce qui donc accentue cette tendance. Résultat : les articles sont de plus en plus courts et les paragraphes aussi. Parfois même un paragraphe = une phrase.

Après, s'il y a désormais des cours d'« écriture web », chaque média et chaque journaliste développe ses propres habitudes. Et là, la notion d'« idée » ou de « groupe d'idées » me paraît assez subjective...

Comment: Merci d'avoir partagé votre expérience !

Answer (score 1):

#### Comment rendre votre blogue intéressant ? ([ca. 2010](https://exob2b.com/pouvez-vous-passer-4-minutes-a-lire-ce-billet/))

**La lecture n’est plus ce qu’elle était avant internet.**

- Les lecteurs en ligne s’attardent en moyenne moins d’une minute par page visitée.
- Le titre, c’est l’accroche ! Utilisez peu de mots, mais des mots forts.

**Pour garder le lectorat intéressé :**

- Structurez vos textes.
- Aérez-les aussi : des paragraphes courts → une idée, un paragraphe.
- Soyez clair et concis : des phrases courtes et simples.
- Schématisez votre raisonnement pour offrir un cheminement logique et facile à suivre.
- Donnez des hyperliens : ils donneront accès à un contenu plus exhaustif à ceux qui voudront approfondir.

---

#### Et en 2018 ?

Internet et la mulitude des humains se sont chargés de rendre désuet ce mode simpliste de composition. On recommande davantage aujourd’hui d’offrir du contenu plus étoffé, et non simplement un texte pouvant parfois s’apparenter à une liste ou une collection de cas.

Mais la recherche continue et les sites internet de haute qualité, auxquels de nombreuses personnes travaillent, mettent à profit les différentes découvertes et analyses disponibles, voire les subventionnent eux-mêmes. Nous ne sommes toujours pas à l’époque, nous sommes peut-être moins que jamais à l’époque où tout un chacun peut y aller selon son feeling, à la va-comme-je-te-pousse et émettre des opinions gratuites qui le catapulteront au sommet de l’audimat.

Il y a bien sûr un certain nombre de ficelles que l’on peut suivre. On recommande entre autres des images, des vidéos, des podcasts, et naturellement des sources et des exemples pour défendre et illustrer son propos.

Et plus récemment, on suggère aussi de miser sur du contenu. Pas une collection de liens vers Wikipédia assortis de quelques phrases pour chacun des sujets qui vous a surpris ou amusé lors de votre dernière escapade dans l’encyclopédie en ligne. Pas une information que tout un chacun peut trouver sur quelques centaines de sites. Non ! L’internaute veut aujourd’hui une réflexion pertinente, originale, peut-être même profonde, qui lui apprendra quelque chose, qui lui fera voir le monde sous un angle qu’il n’avait pas envisagé auparavent.

Tout ceci n’invalide bien sûr pas l’idée de structure organisée, de découpage réfléchi, de titres et de sous-titres pertinents (si pas forcément raccoleurs) et de présentation simple. Des pavés de trois écrans d’ordinateur sans nouveaux paragraphes ne sont pas attirants pour le lecteur, déjà qu’avec l’écran, il perd un peu les [repères](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langages-2010-1-page-29.htm) auxquels l’humain s’était habitué, sans doute inconsciemment, avec les livres :

- la localisation des informations n’est plus aussi facile (un doigt entre deux pages, sur la page de gauche un peu au-dessus du milieu ; des alternatives existent pour les écrans, mais pas aussi intuitive),
- de laquelle découle une plus grande difficulté pour la relecture approfondie, dont on dit que beaucoup de gens rédigeant sur ordinateur impriment leurs textes pour les réviser (je soupçonne que plusieurs pourront se reconnaître ici),
- et finalement se faire une représentation mentale du texte est plus difficile : l’impossibilité de visualiser son contenant en entier nous force à se créer une image faite d’un amalgame des petits morceaux que l’on a vus.

On pourra se demander à la lumière de ces recommendations si Rabelais ou Proust n’auraient pas eu avantage à connaître ces théories, eux qui pouvaient étirer une phrase ou un paragraphe à des proportions proprement *gargantuesques*, lançant le lecteur dans une *recherche du point perdu* dont il revient parfois bredouille.

Probablement pas.

Ces écrivains (auxquels on pourra en ajouter d’autres, dont Nelly Arcand, plus contemporaine et une autre grande amatrice de phrases sans fin) ont publié des livres chez des éditeurs, privilège que ne possèdent pas le commun des mortels, dont les écrits demeurèrent jusqu’à l’arrivée d’internet dans la sphère du privé ou destiné à un lectorat très succint. Les thèses de recherches continuent en cet âge numérique à s’écrire comme elles s’écrivaient jadis. Les romans continuent, comme avant, à refléter la personnalité de l’auteur.

Mais les blogues et forums en ligne obéissent à une dynamique différente. Tous, des meilleurs aux plus minables d’entre nous, peuvent y participer. Comment vais-je m’assurer, en temps que lecteur, que ce texte qu’on me propose vaut bien la peine d’être lu ? Je n’ai plus la garantie d’un éditeur (même si des navets furent et continuent d’être édités aujourd’hui). Je n’ai plus le sceau d’approbation d’une université (même si les connaissances humaines sont contamment rendues désuètes par les nouvelles avancées de la recherche). J’aurai possiblement le sceau d’approbation de quelques amis, voire d’un journal qui se fait le relais d’une constellation de blogues, mais pas forcément non plus, si un blogue commence ou n’a pas des ambitions immenses malgré un contenu parfois très intéressant.

C’est pour ce lecteur justement sceptique que le blogueur doit rapidement établir sa crédibilité et montrer que sa réflexion est intéressante.

L’auteur publié peut se permettre d’élaborer en longueur et de s’étendre. Pas le blogueur.

Il doit utiliser au mieux les résultats des recherches sur la lecture en ligne. Ce faisant, quand dix mille et cent mille blogueurs suivent ces recettes et que des millions d’internautes sont quotidiennement soumis à ce formattage des textes qu’ils lisent, il s’ensuit probablement naturellement que les gens prennent goût à ce format. Les journaux qui veulent conserver leurs lecteurs doivent eux aussi enchaîner le pas et suivre la mesure.